# beautifulsoup "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to do the following:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url=url, headers={ 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT' })
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
HTML_response = response.read()
response.close()
return BeautifulSoup(HTML_response)
```

however, on some pages (always the same pages, but it does not look like order is an issue) I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 268, in _feed
    send(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 439, in __getnewargs__
    return (NavigableString.__str__(self),)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

which does exist, so I don't think doing `except urllib2.HTTPError:` will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import urllib2

In [2]: from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: url = 'http://www.sparklebox.co.uk/topic/creative-arts/art-and-design/colouring-pages.html'

In [4]: request = urllib2.Request(url=url, headers={ 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT' })

In [5]: response = urllib2.urlopen(request)    
In [6]: HTML_response = response.read()    
In [7]: b1 = BeautifulSoup(HTML_response)    
In [8]: print type(b1)
<class 'BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup'>
```

Its working fine with `BeautifulSoup 3.2`

Comment: thanks for this. I upgraded and got the same error.

however, when I tried it your way I did not get an error. I will look further into the problem and update later.

Comment: @rikAtee may you please provide your source code which is causing problem, as I think its almost same code which you've pasted!

Comment: My current code utilises multiprocessing. I tried the BeautifulSoup without multiprocessing and it worked fine - I am still learning multiprocessing so will go back to the drawingboard. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you will get the answer then please close this question by selecting any answer as answer.

Comment: I am also using multiprocessing with beautifulsoup and get this error, I don't see how the answer solves the problem

Comment: @tovmeod did you ever solve this? Am having the same problem using mp

Comment: can't exactly remember what I did back then, I never found the exact problem but I managed to work around it, I suggest you try using a different engine for beautifulsoup, I always used lxml but after some problems (not only this one) I started using htmllib

Comment: Maybe this link gonna help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021254/maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-multiprocessing-and-bs4