# BS4 MemoryError: stack overflow and EOFError: Ran out of input when using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I have a simple python script that utilizes Python's BS4 library and multiprocessing to do some web scraping. I was initially getting some errors where the script would not complete since I would exceed the recursion limit, but then I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021254/maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-multiprocessing-and-bs4) that BeautifulSoup trees cannot be pickled, and so causes issues with multiprocessing, so I followed one recommendation in the top answer which was to do the following: `sys.setrecursionlimit(25000)`

This worked fine for a couple of weeks with no issues (as far as I could tell), but today I restarted the script and some of the processes do not work and I get the error that you can see below:

I now get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/foo/single_items/single_item.py", line 243, in <module>
    Process(target=instance.constant_thread).start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1449, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__, tag))
MemoryError: stack overflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I am not sure what it means, but here is a pseudocode example of the script I have running:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(url):
        self.url = url

    def constant_scrape:
        while True:
            rq = make_get_request(self.url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(rq)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    sys.setrecursionlimit(25000)

    url_list = [...]

    for url in url_list:
        instance = foo(url)
        Process(target=instance.constant_scrape).start()
```

---

**update 1:**
It seems be that it is the same URLs every time that crash even though each url is of (seemingly) the same HTML format as the URLs that do not crash.

Comment: I see some problem in this `While`. When will it stop ?  It will keep calling `make_get_request ` till the python program runs out of memory. Can you explain?

Comment: the requests are made synchronously (not asynchronously) so in theory there should not be any requests made (due to the ```while``` loop) before a previous request is finished. The number of requests made at any one time will not exceed the number of processes created, which is decided out of the while loop.

Comment: Could you give an example of a URL that fails? The problem is likely to be related to the structure of the HTML of that page.

Comment: Also, what code are you using to do the pickling/unpickling? Are you pickling the soup from Beautiful Soup directly, or something else? It will be easiest to help you if you provide code that reproduces your problem.